# How do these simple Python functions work?

Tags: python, function, loops

I have run the the following functions and studied them line-by-line. I understand how the outer for-loop in f(n) works and how the while-loop works in g(n) but I understand the role of the inner for-loop in f(n). Also, how do these loops work with `t = t+1`? Thanks in advance!

```
def f(n):
    t=0
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(2*i):
            t=t+1
    return t

f(5)

def g(n):
     t=0
     j=n
     while j>1:
          t = t+1
          j = j/2
     return t
 
g(32)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. But the `t=t+1` basically means "increment `t` by one". So this counts the total number of loops.

Comment: Ok. So the outer loop runs 5 times calling ```f(n)``` and the inner loop runs 10 times by ```2*i```. Shouldn't that give ```t = 15``` ? The code gives ```t = 20```.

Comment: @mountainscaler no, the outer loop runs 5 times. Each *inner* loop runs 2*i, so it's the sum of 2*i when i goes from 1 - > 5, which is k*(k-1) == 5*4 == 20

Comment: It is clear to me now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop keeps adding 1 to t until it adds 2 times each item from the outer loop. So it adds 0 + 2 + 4 + 6 + 8. The range(5) is similar to a list equivalent to [0,1,2,3,4].

Answer (score 1):

`t=t+1` simply adds 1 to the value of `t` every time the line is run.